# Как сохранять изображения в localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, localstorage

Есть браузерное  приложение (не сайт), для которого нужна такая функция, как cохранять изображение с удаленного url в localStorage. Для того, что бы потом можно выводить в тело dom из локлаьного хранилище . Кто уже такое практиковал поделитесь советом как это реализовать?

Comment: Не решал подобные задачи. Но предполагаю, что придется кодировать изображение в base64 (например через canvas) для сохранения. А дальше после извлечение уже использовать что-то вроде `data:image/png;base64,XXXX`

Comment: Вариант который используется для сайтов [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page) вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам понадобится преобразование изображения в `Base64`:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Теперь вы можете получить изображение из DOM (допустим в целях кэширования), преобразовать его в Base64 и сохранить в `localStorage`:

```
var image = document.getElementById('imageId');
var b64image = getBase64Image(image);
localStorage.setItem('imageIdCached', b64image);
```

Как использовать такое изображение?

```
var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('imageIdCached');
bannerImg = document.getElementById('tableBanner');
bannerImg.src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage;
```