# Хранение фото из ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

делаю форму для загрузки нескольких фото. По ajax Отправляем фото, в ответ от сервера получаем адрес изображения и затем фото вставляется в блок с фото. Вопрос: как и где хранить эти фото в браузере, чтобы можно было их удалять на клиенте как в Вк

Answer (score 0):

что если хранить их в sessionStorage или localStorage?

как вот описано здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450919/490358

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).